# python resolving env variables and extra interpolation at the same time

Tags: python

Using the configparser library, I'm trying to have both interpolation as well as env variables resolving, but it is not happening.

```
import os, configparser

class EnvInterpolation(configparser.BasicInterpolation):
    """Interpolation which expands environment variables in values."""

    def before_get(self, parser, section, option, value, defaults):
        return os.path.expandvars(value)

cfg = """
[Default]
key = world
my_path = ${PYTHONPATH}
path2 = /user/${Default:key} 
[Main]
path_main = Hello.${Default:key}
"""

config = configparser.ConfigParser(interpolation=EnvInterpolation())
config.read_string(cfg)

print(config['Default']['my_path'])
print(config['Default']['path2'])
print(config['Main']['path_main'])
```

I get the result as

```
C:\install\spark\spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python
/user/${Default:key}
Hello.${Default:key}
```

whereas what I want is

```
C:\install\spark\spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python
/user/world
Hello.world
```

If i use the ExtendedInterpolation directly, I get below error.

```
InterpolationMissingOptionError: Bad value substitution: option 'my_path' in section 'Default' contains an interpolation key 'PYTHONPATH' which is not a valid option name. Raw value: '${PYTHONPATH}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By passing the result of EnvInterpolation to another configparser, I'm able to get the required output. Sharing the results so that it could benefit others.

```
import configparser
import os

class EnvInterpolation(configparser.BasicInterpolation):
    """Interpolation which expands environment variables in values."""

    def before_get(self, parser, section, option, value, defaults):
        return os.path.expandvars(value)

cfg = """
[Default]
key = world
my_path = ${PYSPARK_PYTHON}
path2 = /user/${Default:key} 
[Main]
path_main = Hello.${Default:key}
"""

config = configparser.ConfigParser(interpolation=EnvInterpolation())
config.read_string(cfg)

config2 = configparser.ConfigParser(interpolation=configparser.ExtendedInterpolation())
config2.read_dict(config)

print("====1=====")
print(config['Default']['my_path'])
print(config['Default']['path2'])
print(config['Main']['path_main'])

print("====2=====")
print(config2['Default']['path2'])
print(config2['Default']['my_path'])
print(config2['Main']['path_main'])
```

Results:

```
====1=====
C:\install\anaconda\Anaconda3\python.exe
/user/${Default:key}
Hello.${Default:key}
====2=====
/user/world
C:\install\anaconda\Anaconda3\python.exe
Hello.world
```